# Cannot install Powerline fonts

Tags: terminal, font, zsh, font-book, themes

I want to use oh-my-zsh with agnoster theme. So that I've tried to install the required fonts:

- powerline fonts https://github.com/powerline/fonts. For this one I needed not just run `./install.sh` but `sudo sh ./install.sh`, because of the `Permission denied`

Permission denied while installing Fonts without sudo

```
~/fonts (master*) » git remote -v                                                         illia.todorenko@Air-Demir
origin  https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git (push)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/fonts (master*) » ls -la                                                                illia.todorenko@Air-Demir
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  41 illia.todorenko  staff   1312 Jul  4 20:09 .
drwxr-x---+ 39 illia.todorenko  staff   1248 Jul  5 15:22 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 illia.todorenko  staff  10244 Jul  5 10:57 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  13 illia.todorenko  staff    416 Jul  5 10:44 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 illia.todorenko  staff     38 Jul  4 19:38 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x   6 illia.todorenko  staff    192 Jul  4 19:38 3270
drwxr-xr-x  10 illia.todorenko  staff    320 Jul  4 19:38 AnonymousPro
drwxr-xr-x   8 illia.todorenko  staff    256 Jul  4 19:38 Arimo
drwxr-xr-x   8 illia.todorenko  staff    256 Jul  4 19:38 Cousine
drwxr-xr-x   3 illia.todorenko  staff     96 Jul  4 19:38 D2Coding
drwxr-xr-x  10 illia.todorenko  staff    320 Jul  4 19:38 DejaVuSansMono
drwxr-xr-x   7 illia.todorenko  staff    224 Jul  4 19:38 DroidSansMono
drwxr-xr-x   7 illia.todorenko  staff    224 Jul  4 19:38 DroidSansMonoDotted
drwxr-xr-x   7 illia.todorenko  staff    224 Jul  4 19:38 DroidSansMonoSlashed
drwxr-xr-x   9 illia.todorenko  staff    288 Jul  4 19:38 FiraMono
drwxr-xr-x   8 illia.todorenko  staff    256 Jul  4 19:38 GoMono
drwxr-xr-x   9 illia.todorenko  staff    288 Jul  4 19:38 Hack
drwxr-xr-x   8 illia.todorenko  staff    256 Jul  4 19:38 Inconsolata
drwxr-xr-x   7 illia.todorenko  staff    224 Jul  4 19:38 Inconsolata-g
drwxr-xr-x   7 illia.todorenko  staff    224 Jul  4 19:38 InconsolataDz
drwxr-xr-x   3 illia.todorenko  staff     96 Jul  4 19:38 InputMono
drwxr-xr-x  10 illia.todorenko  staff    320 Jul  4 19:38 LiberationMono
drwxr-xr-x  18 illia.todorenko  staff    576 Jul  4 19:38 Meslo Dotted
drwxr-xr-x  18 illia.todorenko  staff    576 Jul  4 19:38 Meslo Slashed
drwxr-xr-x   6 illia.todorenko  staff    192 Jul  4 19:38 Monofur
drwxr-xr-x   5 illia.todorenko  staff    160 Jul  4 19:38 NotoMono
drwxr-xr-x   5 illia.todorenko  staff    160 Jul  4 19:38 NovaMono
drwxr-xr-x   6 illia.todorenko  staff    192 Jul  4 19:38 ProFont
-rw-r--r--   1 illia.todorenko  staff   5400 Jul  4 19:38 README.rst
drwxr-xr-x  16 illia.todorenko  staff    512 Jul  4 19:38 RobotoMono
drwxr-xr-x  20 illia.todorenko  staff    640 Jul  4 19:38 SourceCodePro
drwxr-xr-x  12 illia.todorenko  staff    384 Jul  4 19:38 SpaceMono
drwxr-xr-x   5 illia.todorenko  staff    160 Jul  4 19:38 SymbolNeu
drwxr-xr-x   7 illia.todorenko  staff    224 Jul  4 19:38 Terminus
drwxr-xr-x   8 illia.todorenko  staff    256 Jul  4 19:38 Tinos
drwxr-xr-x  10 illia.todorenko  staff    320 Jul  4 19:38 UbuntuMono
drwxr-xr-x   3 illia.todorenko  staff     96 Jul  4 19:38 fontconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 illia.todorenko  staff   1386 Jul  4 19:38 install.ps1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 illia.todorenko  staff    760 Jul  4 19:38 install.sh
drwxr-xr-x  17 illia.todorenko  staff    544 Jul  4 19:38 samples
-rw-r--r--   1 illia.todorenko  staff    923 Jul  4 19:38 uninstall.sh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/fonts (master*) » ./install.sh                                                          illia.todorenko@Air-Demir
Copying fonts...
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline Bold.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline Bold Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Tinos Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Tinos for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Tinos Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Tinos Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Monofur Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Monofur Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Monofur for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Noto Mono for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Droid Sans Mono for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Symbol Neu for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline LightItalic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Bold for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline Italic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline ExtraLightItalic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline BlackItalic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Semibold for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Medium for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline SemiboldItalic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline BoldItalic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro ExtraLight for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline MediumItalic.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Black for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Source Code Pro Light for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/NovaMono for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Droid Sans Mono Dotted for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Arimo for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Arimo Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Arimo Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Arimo Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x18b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x18n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x24n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x24b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x12b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x12n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x20n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x20b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x16b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x16n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x28b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x28n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x32b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x22b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x22n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x32n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x14n.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ter-powerline-x14b.pcf.gz: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Literation Mono Powerline Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Literation Mono Powerline Bold.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Literation Mono Powerline Bold Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Literation Mono Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Anonymice Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Anonymice Powerline Bold Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Anonymice Powerline Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Anonymice Powerline Bold.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Hack-Regular.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Hack-Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Hack-BoldItalic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Hack-Bold.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ProFont Bold For Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/ProFont For Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Go Mono for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Go Mono Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Go Mono Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Go Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Cousine Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Cousine Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Cousine Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Cousine for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/DejaVu Sans Mono Bold Oblique for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/DejaVu Sans Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Inconsolata for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Inconsolata Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/3270SemiNarrow.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/3270Narrow.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/3270Medium.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L Regular for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S Regular for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M Regular for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Medium for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Thin Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Thin for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Medium Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Light for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Roboto Mono Light Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Inconsolata-g for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Inconsolata-dz for Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Space Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Space Mono Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/SpaceMono-BoldItalic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/SpaceMono-Italic.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/SpaceMono-Bold.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Space Mono Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Space Mono for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M DZ Regular for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M DZ Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S DZ Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L DZ Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S DZ Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L DZ Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L DZ Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S DZ Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M DZ Bold for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG L DZ Regular for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Meslo LG M DZ Italic for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/FuraMono-Regular Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/FuraMono-Bold Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/FuraMono-Medium Powerline.otf: Permission denied
cp: /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts/Droid Sans Mono Slashed for Powerline.ttf: Permission denied
Powerline fonts installed to /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts
```

- menlo for powerline https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline

I made sure these fonts are presented in `~/Library/Fonts`

```
illia.todorenko@Air-Demir  ~/Library/Fonts  ll /Users/illia.todorenko/Library/Fonts | grep Meslo
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   432K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   474K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L Bold for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   432K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L DZ Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   474K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L DZ Bold for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   424K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L DZ Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   465K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L DZ Regular for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   424K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   464K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG L Regular for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   432K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   474K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M Bold for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   432K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M DZ Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   474K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M DZ Bold for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   424K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M DZ Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   465K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M DZ Regular for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   424K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   464K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG M Regular for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   432K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   474K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S Bold for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   432K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S DZ Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   474K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S DZ Bold for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   424K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S DZ Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   465K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   424K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S Italic for Powerline.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   464K Jul  4 19:45 Meslo LG S Regular for Powerline.ttf
```

After that, I still do not see these fonts in `Font Book`.
Even when I click manually on the `Meslo LG S Regular for Powerline.ttf` it says the font is not installed.

[image: Font Book] the same happens even after I click `Install font`. It is not installed.

And in iterm2 I do not see meslo as the available font.

[image: iterm2]

What am I missing? How to fix it?

Comment: Any reason why user fonts are owned by root? Try changing the owner to your user; or at least giving write access.

Comment: how exactly can I do it?

Comment: You're using Powerline: do you know `chown`?

Comment: if I do not install with sudo, then I get `Permission denied`. What is the proper way to install it? My user has admin privileges

Comment: Where are you seeing the "Permission denied" error? All my user fonts are owned by the user.

Comment: Fontbook can’t probably overwrite the font installed in your user account due to the permissions. Remove the fonts from ~/Library/Fonts; check the permission rights for the downloaded fonts (within the folder you have downloaded them) - if necessary correct using _chown_ or via the Info window in Finder; install using Fontbook (or the provided shell script, but maybe take a look what’s happening in there).

Comment: @benwiggy "Where are you seeing the "Permission denied" error? " - please take a look on this extensive gist https://gist.github.com/iamtodor/b238ef16a0bab5e9786b29c8032f1a06

Comment: What happens if you just move/copy the Fonts using the Finder? (You can have sub-folders in ~/Library/Fonts.)

Comment: @benwiggy but that fonts are there, are in the `~/Library/Fonts`. It asks me whether I want to replace it

Comment: you have to change the file ownership permissions. use _chown_ in the terminal or the Info-window in the Finder.

Comment: So you've already got those fonts installed?

Comment: @benwiggy yeah, as I provided it initially. These fonts are in a dir, but I don't see them while configuring iterm

Comment: Does FontBook see them? Can you use them in other applications?

Comment: @benwiggy no - this is the initial ask, initial problem :)

Comment: Sorry: I think we're going round in circles. Have you tried changing the ownership of the fonts in ~/Library/Fonts to your user, not root?

Comment: @benwiggy no, this is exactly what I've asked you in my first question: "how exactly can I do it?" :)

Comment: `sudo chown <nameOfUser> Meslo*` I presumed you were a heavy Terminal user.

Comment: @benwiggy I wiped my system, cause I felt like I have some issue with permission